# Logging a Line in *testing.M

Tags: go

In test functions that take *testing.T or *testing.B as a parameter, it's easy to log a line:

```
func TestMyFunc(t *testing.T) {
    t.Log("hello testing"
    ...
}
```

How do you do this in a setup function that takes *testing.M as a parameter?

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    ???
}
```

Comment: You don't, you can only call `m.Run()`. You have to log it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

A look at the documentation of [package testing](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#M) shows that type `testing.M` has no logging method associated with it. You should do logging using [package log](https://golang.org/pkg/log/) (as already mentioned in the comments).